# Return status-infos from JNI to JAVA

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm calling a long-running JNI-method from my JAVA-application.
The JNI-method does several things and I would like to get a status-message after each step.

I have this JNI-snippet:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_Engine_start(JNIEnv * env, jclass class, jstring address, jstring file) {
    longRunningMethod1();
    // notify java that method 1 is finished

    longRunningMethod2();
    // notify java that method 2 is finished

    longRunningMethod3();    
}
```

and I'm calling the method this way:

```
Engine.start(param1, param2);
```

This method blocks until everything in the JNI is finished - that's ok, but now I would like to get & handle the status-infos.

Maybe something like puts() will help?

Comment: can't you split your JNI method into multiple smaller ones and handle the progress updated between the calls in your app?

Comment: This could work in any way, but it would be a major change. The JNI-method establishes connections to other systems in several threads, and I would like to get infos if those connections are successful or not.

Comment: do a major change and fix your issues properly, instead of hacking your way around then. you'll save time in the long run.

Comment: I will try that if there's no better solution at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as "Andreas Grapentin" mentioned:

> can't you split your JNI method into multiple smaller ones and handle
>   the progress updated between the calls in your app?

It was really no problem here and works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way of notifying the Java side is calling methods.

For a reusable solution define the notifications as methods in an interface. Modify the native method so that it accepts an object that implements the interface as parameter. When the time comes to notify the Java side of interesting having happened, call the appropriate method on that object.

If you care about design patterns, this is basically the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).